# Setup multiple providers with devise :omniauthable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, devise, omniauth

I just got ["Devise 1.2 supports integration with OmniAuth tutorial"](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) working but I'd like to setup multiple providers to refer the same user. I'm looking for some good sample code to look at.

I'm also not sure "multiple providers" is possible with default "devise :omniauthable" implementation and I'd like to reach the "one user many providers" effect, like described by Ryan Bates [235-omniauth-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1), [236-omniauth-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2) but I'm asking if a cleaner way, less hacked mixed models, could be possible in your opinion and may be, if you already know some examples.

thanks in advance
luca

Comment: just seems the best way to go nowadays: [intridea/omniauth 1554w,177forks,last update March 12, 2011] vs [intridea/oauth2 454w,60forks,last update January 12, 2011] or also [pelle/oauth 255w,111forks,last update September 03, 2010] ... don't you think so ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you are asking for code: I have written an article on Devise+Omniauth, that is quite long and consists of source and explainations. It is located here: [http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/11](http://communityguides.heroku.com/articles/11). The approach taken is comparable to the Railscasts you mention.

My implementation of Devise with Omnitauth features multiple providers, Google, Facebook, Twitter and Github. However, I did not test this with Devise 1.2, I am still running 1.1.7. If you find it useful please let me know, if it works for Devise 1.2.

UPDATED jun 14 2011:
... see also, [Omniauth pure: Authentication with Facebook, Google, Google Apps, Twitter, Github, AOL, MyOpenID, ...](http://communityguides.heroku.com/articles/16) This article will demonstrate how to set up a multi-provider authentication using Omniauth only.

Comment: Your last art/tutorial is great. Omniauth pure: Authentication with Facebook, Google, Google Apps, Twitter, Github, AOL, MyOpenID, ... http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16

Comment: Your heroku app is also dead.

Comment: Sorry guys, this answer is quite old, March 2011. Website is gone, however, there is still some code in Github: https://github.com/markusproske/omniauth_pure

Comment: @MarkusProske Please update this post to include relevant code and more up to date links. As it stands, a majority of this post's usefulness went away when the links died.