# Oauth integration with rails project on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been following a [guide](http://xaop.com/blog/2010/03/05/authentication-with-oauth-in-ruby-on-rails/) to integrate the oauth plugin with my rails project. I'm working in windows.

So far I have installed the Oauth gem and the Oauth-plugin gem using the following code:

```
gem install oauth
gem install oauth-plugin
```

both of which have completed successfully. It then says to run the following code:

```
./script/generate oauth_consumer --haml
```

which doesn't work, probably since I'm using rails 3.1 so instead I ran:

```
rails generate oauth_consumer --haml
```

which returns the following message:

could not find generator auth_consumer

**Any ideas what I'm missing? I'm kind of lost and cannot find a better guide.**

a better guide would also help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not too far along with your implementation I can guide you to a better setup which uses the most popular Devise authentication gem along with the oauth gem. I've used devise for a few projects and it truly is the best authentication option available for Rails at the moment.  Devise supports Oauth natively with some configuration. I found this tutorial which might help you:

http://www.railsatwork.com/2010/10/implementing-oauth-provider-part-1.html

[Setup multiple providers with devise :omniauthable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417842/setup-multiple-providers-with-devise-omniauthable)