# Sign in and sign up functionality using oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hello I want to perform functionality like sign in or sign up with facebook using oauth2.

I have generated the consumer controller for oauth and could successfully consume the services provided by facebook.
But now I want to have functionality of sign in and signup.
Im getting a error with this.

My control comes to the def load_consumer but from there it is not going in to def callback2.
If the user is already signed in then it works perfectly fine else it crashes.

And also I wanted to know when to use oauth provider and when to use oauth consumer.

Please if you find a proper documentation for this then please post it here.

Thanks in adavnace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup multiple providers with devise :omniauthable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417842/setup-multiple-providers-with-devise-omniauthable)

Answer (score 1):

There's a live example of how to implement Facebook Login via the Temboo SDK [here](https://www.temboo.com/examples). The source code for that example is available on GitHub (in PHP) but you can easily generate the Ruby code you need to achieve the same behavior via the Temboo website, see link below:

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Facebook/OAuth/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions).